# How do I dual wield weapons in TES Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I know it's possible to dual wield but I have no idea how to do it! Any help?

I am playing on the PS4.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the answer is: Just do it. This might sound stupid, but that's it.

To use **Dual Wield** skills (and learn them), make sure to **equip a one-handed weapon in both hands**. There is no restriction like some other games (e.g. you can dual wield swords just fine, no need to pick daggers).

- Equip any one-handed weapon in your main hand.
- Equip any other one-handed weapon in your off-hand.

You can't dual wield any 2H weapons (staves, greatswords, etc.) and there's no passive available to any class to do it (in contrast to some other games).

Answer (score -1):

Further to the previous answer, you need to be at least level 15 to unlock the second weapon slot

Answer (score -1):

Based on actual game experience:

Prior to level 15, you have only one weapon slot available. That weapon slot can hold one one-handed weapon, one two-handed staff, or two one-handed weapons. If you equip two one-handed weapons in the slot, you will dual wielding when you engage in combat. For example, you could equip two daggers.

After level 15, you have two weapon slots available, which means you can have two different weapon sets that you can switch between during combat. For example, you could equip a two-handed staff in set #1, and two daggers in set #2.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Thank you for your interest in this question. Please include any sources you can find to back up your statement(s), thanks!